# LINQ - using a query expression to calculate data time difference

Tags: linq, datetime, linq-to-entities

I use EntityFramework 4, LINQ, and C#.

I need display data in a GridView from a query expression using Linq; I need project as `anonymous type` a value calculate on fly `DateTime.UtcNow - cl.DateLocked` Note: `cl.DateLocked` is of type `DateTime` and I need to know how many days of difference between this two dates.

With this query I receive an error:

```
DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type.
```

Any idea how to do it in Linq? If Linq does not allow it how to do it in a different way?

Thanks for your time

```
var queryContentsLocked = from cl in context.CmsContentsLockedBies
                          join cnt in context.CmsContents
                          on cl.ContentId equals cnt.ContentId
                          join u in context.aspnet_Users
                          on cl.UserId equals u.UserId
                          select new
                          {
                            cl.DateLocked,
                            cnt.ContentId,
                            cnt.Title,
                            u.UserName,
                            u.UserId,
                            TimePan = DateTime.UtcNow - cl.DateLocked // Problem here!!!
                          };
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var queryContentsLocked = from cl in context.CmsContentsLockedBies
                          join cnt in context.CmsContents
                          on cl.ContentId equals cnt.ContentId
                          join u in context.aspnet_Users
                          on cl.UserId equals u.UserId
                          select new
                          {
                            cl.DateLocked,
                            cnt.ContentId,
                            cnt.Title,
                            u.UserName,
                            u.UserId,
                            Days = SqlFunctions.DateDiff("day", cl.DateLocked, DateTime.UtcNow)
                          };
```

Comment: Thanks @Magnus it is working great. DateDiff method is in namespace: using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient;

Answer (score 2):

Without using any SqlFunction

```
var grandTotalWork = (from t in db.AssignmentHandymandetails
                           join ad in db.AssignmentDetails on t.assignment_detail_id equals ad.assignment_detail_id
                           where ad.assignment_id == Convert.ToInt32(Label_assignmentId.Text)
                            select new { startTime = t.started_time.Value.TimeOfDay, endTime = t.end_time.Value.TimeOfDay, TotalWorkTime = (t.started_time.Value.TimeOfDay.Duration() - t.end_time.Value.TimeOfDay.Duration()).Duration()});
```

then you can bind the result in GridView you wish

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i really appreciate it now the code is readable

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(cl.DateLocked).TotalDays
```

Comment: Error: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. It should be done inside the Linq query expression.